# Azure MySQL did not properly respond after a period of time, failed to respond

Tags: c#, mysql, azure

I have a c# program that will sync data from one database to many other databases. Usually, it will take it 48 hours to finish it. After I updated some code, now when it run about 24 hours. Error will occur, the error message is

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I am wondering what is the possible reason causing this. Is that possible too much connection is created?

How can I find out the cause of this problem?

Suppose I want to find out the root cause, is there any log in Azure MySql that I can see the reason of stop responding? e.g. too many connections or something else?

Comment: How about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview?

If your app is hosted on Azure too, you could turn it on without code modifications, and you could send custom trace logs.

Comment: Either the port is blocked or you cannot reach the host at all for some reason (this is a tcp error message, not a mysql one).

Comment: @Shadow What is the reason that blocked the port? It already run for 24 hours.

Comment: I do not know if blocked port is the actual reason of the error messge. It is one of the potential reasons for this error. I'm sorry, but you need to investigate the issue further yourself.

Comment: Check this out if it helps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/sql-azure-connectivity-troubleshooting-guide/